# Value of $a$ for $x^{2}-4x+4-2a=0$ to have a unique solution

Tags: unique-factorization-domains

By using the **root formula** i got $(2\pm \sqrt{8a})$ expression.

So, **$ a $** cannot be negative and if $a$ is positive we get two solutions.

Therefore, $a=0$ is the answer??

Is my approach correct and is there a better way to solve this problem?

Comment: Your approach is correct (even if things could have been done faster just as Ahmed S. Attaalla answered) but the mistake is $\Delta=16-4(4-2a)=8a$ and the roots are given by $x_{1,2}=\frac{4\pm\sqrt{8a}}2=2\pm \sqrt{2a}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes ,your approach is correct but is seems you incorrectly calculated the roots. It is enough to note that we seek a unique solution to

$$(x-2)^2=2a$$

This is only possible if $a=0$.

And the corresponding solutions are $2\pm \sqrt{2a}$.